# Routing Error on Rails (No Routes match [get])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, passwords

Pretty new to rails as I'm working through the Hartl tutorial. Coming up with an issue that can't quit seem to figure out.

I'm setting up password reset but when clicking on url on generated email I get the following error:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/password_resets/$2a$10$oHhCh6ebtFXLYBKecGsTAu%2FJDc.3FuUKDVacUQTsbLKpiPR6IWTkK/edit"):

**Route file looks like this:**

```
root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users 
  resources(:account_activations, { :only => [:edit] })
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
end
```

**Password Reset Controller**

```
    class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user,         only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user,       only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if password_blank?
      flash.now[:danger] = "Password can't be blank"
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Returns true if password is blank.
    def password_blank?
      params[:user][:password].blank?
    end

    # Before filters

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    # Checks expiration of reset token.
    def check_expiration
      if @user.password_reset_expired?
        flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
        redirect_to new_password_reset_url
      end
    end
end
```

**Finally the mailer url is set up like so:**

```
<%= link_to "Reset Password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

**Routes**

```
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
           sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                 sessions#new
              users_new GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
                   root GET    /                                       static_pages#home
                   help GET    /help(.:format)                         static_pages#help
                  about GET    /about(.:format)                        static_pages#about
                contact GET    /contact(.:format)                      static_pages#contact
                 signup GET    /signup(.:format)                       users#new
                  login GET    /login(.:format)                        sessions#new
                        POST   /login(.:format)                        sessions#create
                 logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                       sessions#destroy
                  users GET    /users(.:format)                        users#index
                        POST   /users(.:format)                        users#create
               new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
              edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit
                   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show
                        PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                        DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format) account_activations#edit
        password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)              password_resets#create
     new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)          password_resets#new
    edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)     password_resets#edit
         password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
                        PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
```

Comment: there is typo `edit_password_resets_url` may be the reason and try specifying action , `method: :post`. And the route `post "password_resets/:id/edit"    => "password_resets#edit"` always expect and `id` so pass id to  `edit_password_reset_url(id)`

Comment: @Sontya edit_password_resets_url led to no method error. Updated my routes.

Comment: how your `link_to` look now?

Comment: `edit_password_reset_path(object)`

Comment: looks the same  <%= link_to "Reset Password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email) %>

Comment: what is `@user.reset_token` it should be `edit_password_reset_path(password_reset_object)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys figured out the issue. I wasn't updating the password reset digest attribute correctly in the user model.

Updated it correctly and seems to be working!